# errbit custom notification backtrace

Tags: airbrake, errbit

I'm sending a custom notification to Errbit using `Airbrake.notify` method. I want to pass the `backtrace`, which is already formatted in proper errbit-ready way, for example:

```
 [{"function"=>"getAttr", "file"=>"[PROJECT_ROOT]/assets/backbone.stickit.js?body=1:285", "line"=>"29"},
 {"function"=>"Stickit.ViewMixin.addBinding", "file"=>"[PROJECT_ROOT]/assets/backbone.stickit.js?body=1:197", "line"=>"26"},
 {"function"=>"Stickit.ViewMixin.addBinding/&#60;", "file"=>"[PROJECT_ROOT]/assets/backbone.stickit.js?body=1:122", "line"=>"11"}]
```

Currently I'm parsing the array to make a string of it and pass it to `Airbrake.notify` as `:backtrace` option, but is it possible to somehow pass the whole array without parsing?